# How to resolve maven dependency chaos to do versioning right?

Tags: java, maven, versioning

I come into the situation that I'm responsible for a legacy Java maven project, and I'm facing some problems with the versioning and the dependencies.

The Project consists of some sub applications, which consists of some modules + all applications (or their modules) also depend on something like a commons module (or better depend on some sub modules of that commons module)

Now I'm facing problems:
1) Seeing the dependencies and changing the version of a module would lead me to a big mess as I don't know where the module is used so I wound have to search for its usings and update manually the version.
Is there a better or other approach that can be used for this dependencies/version mash - maybe tool support (currently using IntelliJ Idea)

2) I'm struggling with an clear approach of versioning for the modules/applications in different Branches.
It is clear for normal release/maintaining breaches - like semantic  versioning, eg minor version is increased and  is stable for that branch, no other branch is using same minor version - that would be the best.
But what if I have to have a branch for same minor version, for another customer - and it has to be in different brunch (it seems in the past and also to the management common product development is a unknown - do other features that should not make it in the other branch (not even disabled, not allowed to be in the code by regulation)).
How to distinguish between the branches? Should I use one of the for version digits for the branch or should I attach to the last digit some characters (eg.: An abbreviation of the project)?
A) 1.5.3.2 (
B) 1.0.3.2-US vs 1.0.3.2-EU
(And yes I know that product with feature toggle it something similar would be the best solution but that's not an option (due to management and regulation obligations))
Question is also if there tooling supports the chosen way.

Comment: The question is why do you have different customer branches? Is the code different ? If yes than you have to have a different version....no doubt about this...otherwise it will be hell...and you will fail..

Answer (score -1):

for 1): Yes, it is. You can use [parent pom](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html) and set version as variable in parent pom. When updating a module version, just update parent pom is enough.

for 2): You can use [git branches](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches) to set different versions for customers. If you use git branches, you need to update all branches when there's new commit. It's also convenient to use different fixes for different customers.

Or you can also solve it by maven through [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html). With different package command like

```
mvn package -PEU
```